# Sending 'awk' results of several files to new files with the same name

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a folder that contains text files. I need to extract 20 lines right after the LAST word 'Input' and send the results to files of the same name in a different folder

I use the following:

```
for i in error/*.log; do awk '/Input/ {n=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=n;i<=n+20;i++) print a[i]}' $i > exceeded/`basename $i` done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do you see an error? Care to share it with us. The only error I can see is a missing semicolon before `done`.

Comment: glenn jackman: no error, just the '>' sign

Comment: @William Pursell: folder already exists.

Comment: The missing semicolon *is* the error. The `done` looks to the shell like a file name argument to Awk, not a statement. Adding a semicolon or newline before it would fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have spaces in the file names (the * part of *.log) then try this:

```
for i in error/*.log; do awk '/Input/ {n=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=n;i<=n+20;i++) print a[i]}' "$i" > "exceeded/`basename \"$i\"`" ; done
```

Also, I am assuming that both the "error" and "exceeded" directories are in the same directory (and that "exceeded" already exists.)

Answer (score 0):

I expect no upvotes for this:

When I hear "do something after the **last** ...", I think "reverse the input and do something after the **first* ..."

This awk only has to remember 20 lines:  helpful if you have large files.

```
for f in error/*.log; do
    tac "$f" | 
    awk -v n=20 -v pattern="input" '
        BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) line[i] = "" }
        function keep_line(l) {
            for (i=2; i<=n; i++) line[i-1] = line[i]
            line[n] = l
        }
        $0 ~ pattern {
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print line[i]
            exit
        }
        { keep_line($0) }
    ' |
    tac > "exceeded/$(basename "$f")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
for i in error/*.log; do
  awk '/Input/ { i=21; delete a; next }
    --i > 0 { a[21-i] = $0 }
    END { for (i=1; i <=20; ++i) print a[i] }' "$i" >exceeded/"${i#error/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in error/*.log; do
    awk 'NR==FNR{if(/Input/)n=NR;next} FNR>n && FNR<(n+21)' "$i" "$i" > exceeded/$(basename "$i")
done
```